# differentiate noisy signal

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, signal-processing, noise

I'm interested in numerically differentiating a noisy signal.

I saw that Stephen Boyd (Convex Optimization, page 312) uses the so-called total variaton method, based on the smoothing function

$\phi_{tv} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\left|\hat{x}_{i+1}-\hat{x}_i  \right| = \left\|D \hat{x} \right\|_1$

The question is: is it more accurate to numerically differentiate the signal de-noised by using this method, or are there more advanced techniques to differentiate noisy data?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. There are many ways to "differentiate" a sampled signal. In general it will be $D x(n) = x \ast h(n)$ for some high-pass filter $h$ ($\ast$ is the convolution). If $x(n) = y(n)+w(n)$ where $w$ is some white noise and $y$ is band-limited, then $h$ will accentuate the noise in the high-frequencies.

Comment: The TV method is effective for signals whose derivative is sparse. If that is not the case, then the result can be wildly inaccurate.